# Trying to make a random number generator in C# unity 4.69

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

According to many sources online, this is exactly how to make a random number generator using C# in unity 4.6, I even saw one youtube video write it exactly how I did, but it doesn't seem to work for me, the error message says "the name 'n' does not exist in the current context".

I've also looked at similar C# questions to this that have been solved on stackoverflow and tried the same solutions and all I get are errors.

Here is my code:

```
void Start () {
    n = Random.Range (1, 1000);
    print (n);
}
```

Comment: That is an invalid C# syntax. You need to define the variable n before using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must declare a variable before using it. Declare `n` before using it:

```
int n = 0;
void Start () 
{
    n = Random.Range (1, 1000);
    print (n);
}
```

OR

```
void Start ()
{
    int n = Random.Range (1, 1000);
    print (n);
}
```

Now, if you get the error:

> 'Random' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Random' and
>   'System.Random'

That's because `System` and `UnityEngine` are both imported with `using System;` and `using  UnityEngine`Use

```
UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 1000);
```

Comment: You are welcome. You need to see [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting) C# tutorial for Unity beginners.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll have a look through it.